# How to print in a tabular format in tcl?

Tags: format, tcl

I am trying to print the data in a tabular format in tcl. Suppose I have three arrays:-

`GOLD, TEST, DIFF` and it has some values in it. I want to get in printed in the following format:-

> GOLD            TEST          DIFF 
>   -----------       --------       ---------
>        1               Hello            Hi
>        2               Stack          Format
>        3               Guys           for
>        4               TCL            print

Would you guys like to suggest something?

Comment: When you say 'array' do you mean a tcl array or did you mean lists of values? Tcl arrays (what some languages call a hash map) are unordered, so how would the solution know in what order to print the values? Do the arrays share a common set of keys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's code that does what you want with a single foreach loop.  There's no need to create temporary lists - assuming you have common indexes for the arrays (you didn't specify).

```
array set GOLD {a 1 b 2 c 3 d 4}
array set TEST {d TCL c Guys b Stack a Hello}
array set DIFF {a Hi c for b Format d print}
foreach idx [lsort [array names GOLD]] {
  puts "$GOLD($idx)\t$TEST($idx)\t$DIFF($idx)"
}
```

If you don't have common indexes for the arrays (then I wonder question the utility of the printed table), you can do this (though the relative ordering is undefined):

```
foreach {gidx gval} [array get GOLD] {tidx tval} [array get TEST] {didx dval} [array get DIFF] {
  puts "$gval\t$tval\t$dval"
}
```

Answer (score 17):

I would use the [format](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/format.htm) command combined with [foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm) to accomplish what you're asking for. I'm assuming you actually have 3 lists, not 3 arrays, since it would appear the values of gold, test, diff are related to each other in some way.

```
set goldList {1 2 3 4}
set testList {Hello Stack Guys TCL}
set diffList {Hi Format for print}

set formatStr {%15s%15s%15s}
puts [format $formatStr "GOLD" "TEST" "DIFF"]
puts [format $formatStr "----" "----" "----"]
foreach goldValue $goldList testValue $testList diffValue $diffList {
    puts [format $formatStr $goldValue $testValue $diffValue]
}

# output
       GOLD           TEST           DIFF
       ----           ----           ----
          1          Hello             Hi
          2          Stack         Format
          3           Guys            for
          4            TCL          print
```

Answer (score 4):

First convert the arrays into lists:

```
set GOLDList ""
set keyList [array names GOLD]
foreach key $keyList {
    lappend GOLDList $GOLD($key)
}
```

Then you can use the foreach snippet:

```
set GOLDList "1 2 3 4"; #1st list
set TESTList "Hello Stack Guys TCL"; #2nd list
set DIFFList "Hi Format for print"; #3rd list

foreach c1 $GOLDList c2 $TESTList c3 $DIFFList {
    puts $c1\t$c2\t$c3
}
```

That is the output (you need to print the header extra)

```
1   Hello   Hi
2   Stack   Format
3   Guys    for
4   TCL     print
```

Comment: But note that arrays do not have defined ordering of their keys when their elements are extracted using `array get` (or their keys extracted using `array names` etc), so if the original poster did really mean he/she has arrays and not lists, this effect should be taken care of when iterating over arrays in parallel or serializing them into lists.

Comment: Yes, you're right, there is no order in the array. You can use array names order, but the post author did not say anything about that, so I think he don't care about it. I add a snippet to my post for converting an array into a list. @kostix

Answer (score 3):

One more complex option would be to use the [report](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/md/tcllib/files/modules/report/report.md) package from tcllib.

But thats probably not worth it for this simple case.